# Distribution of linear transformation and inverse linear transformation over union, intersection.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I have the following question:

> [image]

But I do not know how to start solving it, especially because as we know that representation of a linear transformation is not that easy. shall I use the matrix representation of a linear transformation?

I am unable to solve this problem, could anyone help me in doing so, please? giving example of how to proceed will be very helpful.

Comment: If you first answer this question without worrying about linearity you should be able to get the answer with linearity.

Comment: I do not understand your comment, you mean I should worry about scalar multiplication first?@KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: All equalities but $(2)$ are true for any map, so in particuler for a linear map. For $(2)$ and a general map; we have only ${}\subseteq{}$. So examine whether the reverse inclusion is satisfied ny a linear map.

Comment: Is it a proof like the ordinary one of function and inverse functions in topology books? yeah your explanation was very clear @Bernard  thanks! :))

Comment: For the general equalities, it's a high school exercise. For the reverse inclusion, I don't have time now to think of it, but in my opinion, whether it's true or there's a counter example, it is very general and has nothing to do with matrices, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for the reverse inclusion of** $\boldsymbol{(2)}$:

One does not have in general $f(A)\cap f(B)\subseteq f(A\cap B)$.

Consider the $x y$-plane, and two distinct lines $\ell,\ell'\,$ through the origin, an take  for the linear map $\alpha$ the projection onto the $x$-axis. What are $\alpha(\ell)$ and $\alpha(\ell')$? What is $\ell\cap\ell'$?

Comment: so you are saying if it is in general not true for any map so in particular, it is not true for a linear map..... correct?

Comment: No. I produce a counter example with a linear map. If it's false for a general map, it nevertheless  *might* be true for linear maps. This shows it isn't true for linear maps either (but it might be true for *some* linear maps).